# Cannot find my plan for the new Azure Function App

Tags: azure, azure-functions

I am trying to create an Azure Function App. Before that, I created a free App Service plan. Now, as I am creating the function app, I don't see that plan in the dropdown, even though I use the same resource group, operating system and region for both plan and the function app. Thus I cannot create the function app. What am I missing?

Comment: Have you selected the `plan type` as `App service Plan` while creating the function app from the portal and also were you able to see that created app service plan under resource group resources or in All resources ?

Comment: @VenkateshDodda-MSFT Yes, I selected it as App Service Plan, and I see it in the resource group.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Specified in this [MS Doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/dedicated-plan) of Azure Functions Dedicated Plan, all other SKU's like Basic to Premium are allowed except F1 (Free Tier) in Azure Functions - Dedicated Hosting Plan:

[image]

**Practical**:

[image]

**Result**:
[image]

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Could you please provide a link to the documentation you mentioned? The link you provided points to the picture and not to the text.

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/dedicated-plan